# Compatible Hibernate version with Spring ORM 4.1.7 Release

Tags: hibernate, spring-orm

I am using Spring ORM 4.1.7 Release and I want to integrate hibernate with this version. I have tried hibernate 3.6.10.Final but some class are missing in that, if I use hibernate 4.3.10.Final some other classes are missing. I guess, I have to use both to proceed ahead. When I saw Spring ORM 4.1.7 Release POM, it is referring to 2 different versions of hibernate core. Is that valid in a single POM file?

Which hibernate core version I should use to move ahead. Please help

Answer (score 0):

The spring framework supports multiple hibernate implementations and the dependencies are defined as *optional* because it's end user controlled as to which subpackage of hibernate you'll need to interact with based on your application's own Hibernate version.

I would suggest that if you can use Hibernate 5, do so.  The Hibernate 4.x branch is being phased and Hibernate 3 is no longer supported from a bugfix perspective.